# can you set a variable in a function as the name given in the parameters?

Tags: php, function

if I have a function:

```
function abc($var1,$var2){
   $var1 = 'this is var1';
   $var2 = 'this is var2';
}
```

how can I set variables and use the name provided in the parameter as some string defined in the function?

So if I were to run:

`abc($useThis , $andThis);`

How can I have it return:

```
// $useThis  == 'this is var1'
// $andThis  == 'this is var2'
```

I know the parameters are used as an *input*, but can they be used in the opposite way?

Comment: Three nigh identical answers (especially after recent edits) within the first four minutes. Looks like you have your solution xD

Comment: @TheZ I was just going to mention that! Did you see the progression of edits! lol...from links, down to voting it was identical haha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply pass the parameters by [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) instead of passing by value.

```
function abc(&$var1,&$var2){
   $var1 = 'this is var1';
   $var2 = 'this is var2';
}
```

Comment: AWESOME!! perfect! (you answered first..i think...)

Comment: @iight Looks like Musa was first by 10 seconds. It was really really close.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) to modify variables passed to php functions, put an `&` sign before the parameter to pass them by reference

```
function abc(&$var1,&$var2){
   $var1 = 'this is var1';
   $var2 = 'this is var2';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can [pass-by-reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) in PHP.

Prepend the parameters with an ampersand:

```
function abc(&$var1, &$var2){
   $var1 = 'this is var1';
   $var2 = 'this is var2';
}
```